# How to recursively ask for input when given wrong date format for two raw input and continue the operation in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get two dates as input and convert is epoch time, but i need the two different dates given as input to be validated in correct format else recursively ask for correct input.

```
from datetime import date 

import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(raw_input('Enter Start date in the format DD-MM-YYYY: '), '%d-%m-%Y')
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(raw_input('Enter Start date in the format DD-MM-YYYY: '), '%d-%m-%Y')
epoch_date = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)

diff1 = (start_date - epoch_date).days
diff2 = (end_date - epoch_date).days

epoch1 = (diff1 * 86400)
epoch2 = (diff2 * 86400)

print('\nPTime_Start: %i' % diff1), 
print("&"),
print('PTime_End: %i' % diff2)

print('Epoch_Start: %i' % epoch1), 
print("&"),
print('Epoch_End: %i' % epoch2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using Python 3.x and Python 3.x does not have any function that is called "raw_input()". It has been changed to "input()".

```
def take_date_input():
    input_date = input('Enter date in the format DD-MM-YYYY: ')
    try:
        one_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
    except ValueError:
        return take_date_input()
    return one_date
```

You can do this if you really want recursiveness in your code but it would be better with while loop.